# Wireshark lua scripting to dissect CoAP option

Tags: lua, wireshark, coap

I'm writing lua script to dissect coap protocol. However I cannnot get coap options(URI-Path) of 2nd or later if there are several same options.

```lua
do
 local test_proto = Proto("test_proto", "Test Protocol")
 local test_uripath = ProtoField.string("test.uripath", "Uri-Path")
 test_proto.fields = {test_uripath}
 local coap_uripath = Field.new("coap.opt.uri_path")
 function test_proto.dissector(tvbuffer, pinfo, treeitem)
  local subtree = treeitem:add(test_proto)
  subtree:add(test_uripath, tostring(coap_uripath().value))
 end
register_postdissector(test_proto)
end
```

Only first URI-Path is displayed at subtree even if coap URI-Path option has several values like the following.

```
Opt Name: #1: URI-Path: XXX
Opt Name: #2: URI-Path: YYY
```

I can only get XXX by using [coap.opt.uri_path](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/c/coap.html). How can I get 2nd or later same option fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in all fields and not just the first one, then you'll need to process the entire table.  For example:

```
do
    local test_proto = Proto("test_proto", "Test Protocol")
    local test_uripath = ProtoField.string("test.uripath", "Uri-Path")
    test_proto.fields = {test_uripath}

    local coap_uripath = Field.new("coap.opt.uri_path")

    function test_proto.dissector(tvbuffer, pinfo, treeitem)
        local subtree = treeitem:add(test_proto)
        local coap_uripath_table = { coap_uripath() }

        for i,uripath in ipairs(coap_uripath_table) do
            subtree:add(test_uripath, tostring(uripath.value))
        end
    end

    register_postdissector(test_proto)
end
```

See also:
https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/35682/lua-accessing-multiple-smb2msg_id-values
https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/1579/fetching-multiple-named-values-with-lua

Comment: Christopher, Thank you so much! My issue is completely solved.